# confused with lua if statement! ( i'm a beginner )

Tags: lua

How do you use a statement to see if a variable equals a certain string? it says there is an issue with the equal symbol at least think but i'm not very used to lua as i started about a week ago.

```
adjective = "awesome"
noun = "maxhifive"
print(noun .. " is so " .. adjective)
if adjective = "awesome" then 
  print ("he is so cool B]")
end
```

i want it to check for the variable value but im not sure how

Comment: you stated "it says there is an issue..." you should include that error message in your question.

Comment: And maybe read the book, at least the important pages: https://www.lua.org/pil/3.2.html

Answer (score 1):

In common with many other languages Lua distinguishes between assignment and equality by using a different operator symbol.  The equality operator is `==` not `=`.

```lua
adjective = "awesome"
noun = "maxhifive"
print(noun .. " is so " .. adjective)
if adjective == "awesome" then 
  print ("he is so cool B]")
end
```